# How to resolve Checkout page continues loading issue?

Tags: php, magento2.1

I am facing the issue in the checkout page, After clicking the "proceed checkout" from cart page then page continuously loading.

I have observed in console some require js issues are there, exactly I didn't find a solution for those console errors. Please check the attached screenshot for your reference.

[image]

console issues are

```
TypeError: window.checkoutConfig.payment is undefined[Learn More] vault.js:20:9
TypeError: quote.totals(...) is undefined[Learn More] totals.js:15:40
TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
```

Help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps:-**

```
Remove the pub/static/frontend  : rm -rf pub/static/frontend

chmod -R 777 pub/*

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Make sure the JS existing on the path as mentioned in the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Rakesh, I have tried what you mentioned still same issue